# How to measure information (JSON) trafficked to REST service in hybrid mobile application

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework

I have a hybrid application built with Ionic, which makes requests to a REST service. I need to limit the amount of information sent daily to the service in order to save the user's mobile data when used in 3G / 4G. Is there a way to measure the amount of information in kb or mb in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of this in server side, and include a field in your json response with this data for every request.